# Gmail like Checkbox functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to implement gmail like checkbox functionality:
In which If CheckAll checkbox is clicked, all listed checkbox will be selected/unselected, if all listed checkbox are selected, CheckAll checkbox will be checked. and if only some checkbox are checked, - sign checkbox will be appear.

I have implement logic using div.
Here is the logic:
**HTML:**

```
<table id="ViewTable" class="tableEffectfull">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="selectCol"><div class="unCheckedCheckBoxAll"></div></th>
            <th class="nosCol">Products</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="unCheckedCheckBox"></div></td>
        <td>ABCD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="unCheckedCheckBox"></div></td>
        <td>PQRS</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.unCheckedCheckBox{
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   margin-top: -4px;
   background: transparent url(images/prettyCheckable-green.png) top left no-repeat;
}
.CheckedCheckBox{
   background: transparent url(images/prettyCheckable-green.png) 0 -60px;
}
.unCheckedCheckBoxAll{
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   margin-top: -4px;
   background: transparent url(images/Checkable-green.png) top left no-repeat;
}
.CheckedCheckBoxAll{
   background: transparent url(images/Checkable-green.png) 0 -60px;
}
```

**Script:**
//updated scripts:

```
$(".unCheckedCheckBox").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('CheckedCheckBox');
  $('.unCheckedCheckBoxAll').toggleClass('CheckedCheckBoxAll', $('.CheckedCheckBox').length == $(".unCheckedCheckBox").length)
});
$(".unCheckedCheckBoxAll").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('CheckedCheckBoxAll');
  $('.unCheckedCheckBox').toggleClass('CheckedCheckBox')
});
```

Now the problem is I am not getting what to do if all listed checkbox are selected, make checkedAll checkbox to be checked and if some are checked only highlighted checkbox will be display in checkedAll.

Below is the Image I am using:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

> http://jsfiddle.net/VrkA3/1/

I have changed the script :

```
$(".unCheckedCheckBox").click(function () {
$(this).toggleClass('CheckedCheckBox');
if ($('.CheckedCheckBox').length == 2) {
    $('.CheckBoxAll').addClass('CheckedCheckBoxAll').removeClass('minusCheckBoxAll')
} else {
    $('.CheckBoxAll').removeClass('CheckedCheckBoxAll')
    if ($('.CheckedCheckBox').length == 0) 
$('.CheckBoxAll').removeClass('minusCheckBoxAll')
        else $('.CheckBoxAll').addClass('minusCheckBoxAll')
    }
});

$(".CheckBoxAll").click(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('minusCheckBoxAll')
    $(this).toggleClass('CheckedCheckBoxAll');
    $('.unCheckedCheckBox').toggleClass('CheckedCheckBox',   $(this).is('.CheckedCheckBoxAll'))
});
```

added a two new css classes too...

```
.unCheckedCheckBox {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    background: red top left no-repeat;
}
.CheckedCheckBox {
    background: pink 0 -60px;
}
.CheckBoxAll {
    background: white;
}
.unCheckedCheckBoxAll {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    background: blue top left no-repeat;
}
.CheckedCheckBoxAll {
    background: black 0 -60px;
}
.minusCheckBoxAll {
    background: green 0 -60px;
}
```

Comment: thanks... I like the logic. BTW I am using above image for display checkbox.

Comment: so what is the minus state - means ?

Comment: Minus state for only some of the listed checkboxes are checked.

Comment: Yes but I was asking for the image of the check box for minus state

Comment: For minus state Currently I am using 2nd checkbox, that is the highlighted checkbox. Well, I accepted the answer just because it helps me to implement functionality of image too. Will update my question soon with answer using image. which will be helpful to others. Thanks for support. Best Luck...

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".unCheckedCheckBox").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('CheckedCheckBox');
    $('.unCheckedCheckBoxAll').toggleClass('CheckedCheckBoxAll', $('.CheckedCheckBox').length == $(".unCheckedCheckBox").length)
});
$(".unCheckedCheckBoxAll").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('CheckedCheckBoxAll');
  $('.unCheckedCheckBox').toggleClass('CheckedCheckBox', $(this).is('.CheckedCheckBoxAll'))
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uKePd/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using above images to implement my logic

Answer (score 3):

Try this and get an idea about how to do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/FdEhf/

```
<input type="checkbox" class="all" value="all">Check all
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="2">
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="3">
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="4">
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="5">
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="6">
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="7">
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="8">
```

Script,

```
$("input.all").on("change", function (e) {
    $(':checkbox').prop("checked",$(this).is(":checked"))
});
```

***Update***

---

http://jsfiddle.net/FdEhf/2/

```
$(document).on("change", ".all:not('.minus')", function (e) {
    $(':checkbox').prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
});

$(document).on("change", ".all.minus", function (e) {
    $(':checkbox').prop("checked", false);
    $(".all").removeClass("minus");
});
$(document).on("change", ":checkbox:not('.all')", function (e) {
    if ($(':checkbox').not(".all").length == $(':checkbox:checked').not(".all").length) {
        $(".all").prop("checked", true).removeClass("minus");
    } else {
        $(".all").prop("checked", false).addClass("minus");
        if ($(':checkbox:checked').not(".all").length == 0) {
            $(".all").removeClass("minus");
        }
    }
});
```

***UPDATE2***

---

Updated to your approch based on your request.http://jsfiddle.net/FdEhf/4/

```
<table id="ViewTable" class="tableEffectfull">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="selectCol">
                <div class="unCheckedCheckBoxAll"></div>
            </th>
            <th class="nosCol">Products</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="unCheckedCheckBox"></div>
        </td>
        <td>ABCD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="unCheckedCheckBox"></div>
        </td>
        <td>PQRS</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Script,

```
$(document).on("click", ".unCheckedCheckBoxAll:not('.minus')", function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('CheckedCheckBoxAll');
    $('.unCheckedCheckBox').toggleClass('CheckedCheckBox');
});

$(document).on("click", ".unCheckedCheckBoxAll.minus", function (e) {
    $('.unCheckedCheckBox').removeClass('CheckedCheckBox');
    $(this).removeClass("minus");
});
$(document).on("click", ".unCheckedCheckBox", function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("CheckedCheckBox");
    if ($('.unCheckedCheckBox').length == $('.CheckedCheckBox').length) {
        $(".unCheckedCheckBoxAll").removeClass("minus");
    } else {
        $(".unCheckedCheckBoxAll").removeClass("CheckedCheckBoxAll").addClass("minus");
        if ($('.CheckedCheckBox').length == 0) {
            $(".unCheckedCheckBoxAll").removeClass("minus");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually by clicking on checkall, making all checkbox marked is done.other two functionalities I am not able to implement.

Comment: the OP is not using `input`s

Comment: yes. but js logic is there. you can understand the logic now and convert it to your approach\

Comment: @Reigel: no it is not. http://jsfiddle.net/FdEhf/2/ is the way it should if you are using inputs

Comment: @ITBeginner: see the UPDATE2 and it is the correct answer for you